# Rails 500 server error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing a 500 internal error in my navigator's console.

in the server console :

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 359ms

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template questions/vote_for,
>   application/vote_for with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/home/seif/Documents/ROR/Voting_trial/StackUnderflow/app/views" ):
>   app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:90:in `vote_for'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/seif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb
>   within rescues/layout (0.5ms)

what is the problem?

this is the vote_for action:

```
def vote_for
  logger.info "***vote for***!!!"
  logger.info params[:id]
  @quest_vote_for = Question.find(params[:id])
  current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@quest_vote_for)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

and this is the view call :

```
<%=link_to raw( vote_for, vote_for_question_path(@question), :remote => true,:class =>"btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more clear... The error is because the templates cannot be found.

First if you do want to support js and html responses then you need a template for both.

So you need ONE of the following:

```
/app/views/questions/vote_for.html.erb
/app/views/application/vote_for.html.erb (bad practice)
```

AND one of the following

```
/app/views/questions/vote_for.js.erb
/app/views/questions/vote_for.js.coffee
/app/views/application/vote_for.js.erb (bad practice)
/app/views/application/vote_for.js.coffee (bad practice)
```